# library(dplyr) causes r studio to crash

Tags: r, rstudio

I just upgraded to R 3.1.1 in order to check out tidyr. However, as soon as I call `library (dplyr)` rstudio terminates-even right after starting r-studio with no other packages loaded. I´ve tried both the cran version (0.2) and the developmental version.

I´m on R studio Version 0.98.994 and mac os x mavericks. Any ideas?

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin13.1.0                
system         x86_64, darwin13.1.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.1                         
year           2014                        
month          07                          
day            10                          
svn rev        66115                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
nickname       Sock it to Me
```

Edit: The same issue also arises when I load amelia, plyr and mice. I see that these all depend on Rcpp. However, all my packages were checked for updates.

OK--I loaded up R GUI without R studio and it crashes so it is not the fault of R studio. I get the following errormsg:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
 3: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
 4: asNamespace(ns)
 5: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,     .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
 6: loadNamespace(package, c(which.lib.loc, lib.loc))
 7: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 8: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 9: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
10: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
11: try({    ns <- loadNamespace(package, c(which.lib.loc, lib.loc))    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)})
12: library(dplyr)
```

In the end I did a new complete reinstallatin of both R 3.1.1 and R studio. For some reason it is now working.

Comment: It's a bug. Report it to the maintainers.